# PIVOT Multiple Rows to Different Column with Additional Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I need your suggestion on this.

I have a before table like below, which I would like to transform to the after table,

(note: the table below is just an example, there is over 1000+ rows in the real table)

Before:

| line_type | line_name | op_id | org_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Internal | Storage 1 | 1 | ABC |
| Makloon | Storage 2 | 1 | DEF |
| Process | Storage 2 | 1 | XYZ |
| Internal | Storage 3 | 2 | XYZ |
| Makloon | Storage 1 | 2 | ABC |
| Process | Storage 2 | 2 | XYZ |

After:

| op_id | org_code internal | Internal | org_code Makloon | Makloon | org_code Process | Process |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | Storage 1 | DEF | Storage 2 | XYZ | Storage 2 |
| 2 | XYZ | Storage 3 | ABC | Storage 1 | XYZ | Storage 2 |

Can I use `PIVOT` for this case? Or do I need to use another way?

I have only succeeded in using `PIVOT` for the `line_name`, I'm not sure how to `PIVOT` both of them (`line_name` and `org_code`)

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT 
    [op_id], 
    [Internal],
    [Makloon],
    [Process]
FROM
    (SELECT
         [line_type],
         [line_name],
         [op_id]
     FROM 
         [database_name]
    ) pvt
PIVOT 
    (MAX(line_name)
        FOR [line_type] IN ([Internal], [Makloon], [Process])
    ) AS pvt_table
ORDER BY 
    [op_id];
```

The result of this query:

| op_id | Internal | Makloon | Process |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Storage 1 | Storage 2 | Storage 2 |
| 2 | Storage 3 | Storage 1 | Storage 2 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pivot is just a fancy CASE WHEN expression, and it's often easier to spell it out manually:

```sql
SELECT op_id
,   MAX(case when line_type = 'Internal' THEN org_code END) AS org_code_internal
,   MAX(case when line_type = 'Internal' THEN line_name END) AS internal
,   MAX(case when line_type = 'Makloon' THEN org_code END) AS org_code_Makloon
,   MAX(case when line_type = 'Makloon' THEN line_name END) AS internal_Makloon
,   MAX(case when line_type = 'Process' THEN org_code END) AS org_code_Process
,   MAX(case when line_type = 'Process' THEN line_name END) AS Process

FROM (
    VALUES  (N'Internal', N'Storage 1', 1, N'ABC')
    ,   (N'Makloon', N'Storage 2', 1, N'DEF')
    ,   (N'Process', N'Storage 2', 1, N'XYZ')
    ,   (N'Internal', N'Storage 3', 2, N'XYZ')
    ,   (N'Makloon', N'Storage 1', 2, N'ABC')
    ,   (N'Process', N'Storage 2', 2, N'XYZ')
) t (line_type,line_name,op_id,org_code)
group by op_id
```

By this method, you can flip almost any kind of rows

Comment: Thankyou, I tried it and it worked just like what I expected

Comment: @lolster When you find an answer that works, please ACCEPT it.   This serves two purposes 1) A thank you for the contributor's time and talent, and 2) Indicates to other contributors that the issue has been resolved.